# ScriptCS 0.17.01 Error Unexpected named argument

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, scriptcs, vscode-code-runner

I tried to run my program using Visual Studio's Coderunner extension as well as from terminal with the scriptcs command.

My code is as follows:

```
using System;
namespace HelloWorldApplication {
class HelloWorld {
   static void Main(string[] args) {
      Console.WriteLine("hellowol");
   }
}
}
```

The error message reads:

```
Unexpected named argument: Users/jfitz/Projects/C#/Projtest/test.cs
```

Comment: Would https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/1188#issuecomment-410728346 help? If os, I will post an answer later today.

Comment: Worked! Thanks @VonC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in [`scriptcs/scriptcs` issue 1188](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/1188#issuecomment-410728346), this is from a scriptcs bug, which will be fixed in the next release ([PR 1289](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/1188#issuecomment-410728346) and [commit 9e49b72](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/commit/9e49b72a5c032878d7a87421229701d2828b7b3e))

In the meantime, pending the [next 0.18 scriptcs release](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/releases):

> The workaround is the following:
>
> instead of doing
>
> ```
> mono scriptcs.exe /path/to/foo.csx
> ```
>
> do:
>
> ```
> mono scriptcs.exe -script /path/to/foo.csx
> ```

[Jonas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/291356/jonas) suggests [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51924614/scriptcs-0-17-01-error-unexpected-named-argument/51936979?noredirect=1#comment104572970_51936979):

> For Visual Studio Code, add this to `settings.json`:
>
> ```
> "code-runner.executorMap": { "csharp": "scriptcs -script" }
> ```

Comment: For **Visual Studio Code** add this to `settings.json`
`"code-runner.executorMap": {
        "csharp": "scriptcs -script"
    }`

Comment: @jonas Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Small note that it take me some time in debian (and i assume most of linux systems) the file is located at ~/.config/Code/User

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem of code runner extention. to resolve it click on extentions icon in vs code and select code runner , beside of uninstall button click on setting icon -> extention setting -> find code runner : executor map then click on edit in setting.json . In line 27 replace this  "csharp": "scriptcs" by this "csharp": "scriptcs -script"

Comment: Based on vonc's answer, it seems this is not an extension issue but a scriptcs version issue. Can you cite your source (which will help elaborate this detail)?